# stream subscription throwing an error in dart in flutter app?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using the `connectivity` plugin in my flutter to check for the connection status, but occasionally hitting the error `PlatForm Exception(No active stream to cancel, null)` even though i have handled the null case. I have subscribed to the stream in `initState` and cancelled the subscription in `dispose` state

my code looks something like this.

```
    StreamSubscription streamConnectionStatus;
    ------------
    //remaining code
    ------------
    @override
    void initState() {
    getConnectionStatus();
  }

getConnectionStatus() async {
    streamConnectionStatus = new Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      // Got a new connectivity status!

      if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
          result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        setState(() {
          boolHasConnection = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          boolHasConnection = false;
        });
      }
    });

@override
  void dispose() {
    try {
      streamConnectionStatus?.cancel();
    } catch (exception, stackTrace) {
      print(exception.toString());
      updateError(exception.toString(), stackTrace);
    } finally {
      super.dispose();
    }
  }
```

this is actually driving me crazy but i am guessing i am missing something or do i have to change the code.

Many thanks,
Mahi

Comment: It looks like you may have a copy and paste issue with `getConnectionStatus()` nested within `initState`. Also, can you provide more debugging information such as what scenarios are more likely to lead to the error getting through? What if you do the null check without the shortcut operator?

Comment: thanks @AshtonThomas i have now edited the question. yes it was a copy and paste issue. sorry about the mistake. I have tried the exclusive null check as well instead of the Nullaware operator. but still the same issue. The problem is it doesn't happen every time., throws error only once in a while. this is a bit hard to figure out without code, but i was just trying if anyone was facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm out of my area of understanding, but could the `streamConnectionStatus` object be present but the `Stream` that it was connected to is no longer available?

Comment: hi Ashton, hmm that could be the case, then the `streamConnectionStatus` I think should be null and should not atleast throw any exception as we are still checking for a `null`. please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: My thought is that you may be storing a subscription (or something like that) which is not null, but the stream that the subscription is tied too has gone away somehow. Honestly, I don't know if the problem could be something like this. Just throwing it out there

Comment: hmm, this could be the case but I've actually subscribed to the `broadcastStream` how can this throw an exception. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue. This is what helped me.

I had subscribed the stream exposed by connectivity plugin in different widgets in the same widget tree. I removed the subscription from child widgets and retained the subscription only in the parent and passed on the connection status to the children from parent.

By doing so my code got more cleaner and the stream subscription was maintained / disposed only at one place. Then I didn't encounter this issue any more.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I will do the same as well and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `dispose` function is defined inside `getConnectionStatus`. The IDE might not throw error as it still is a valid definition. Just remove it from inside and make sure it lies in the respective class. Your code just works like a charm.

Example:

```
class ConnectivityExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ConnectivityExampleState createState() => new _ConnectivityExampleState();
}

class _ConnectivityExampleState extends State<ConnectivityExample> {
  StreamSubscription streamConnectionStatus;

  bool boolHasConnection;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getConnectionStatus();
  }

  Future<Null> getConnectionStatus() async {
    streamConnectionStatus = new Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      debugPrint(result.toString());

      if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
          result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        setState(() {
          boolHasConnection = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          boolHasConnection = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  // dispose function inside class
  @override
  void dispose() {
    try {
      streamConnectionStatus?.cancel();
    } catch (exception, stackTrace) {
      print(exception.toString());
    } finally {
      super.dispose();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: new Text(boolHasConnection.toString()),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks @HemanthRaj that was really helpful , i've checked the dispose method and it is actually in the State class. This exception only occurs occasionally but it's kind of bugging me and I can't figure out why it is doing this. But, thank you very much for your help.